# Не работает скрипт jQuery на Mac Os

Tags: html, jquery, macos

Я написал код который должен динамично генерировать таблицу для навигации по контенту.

1. Вытянул все элементы `h1` из блока `content` и присвоить им
   `id`(якорь).
2. Затем, используя эти `h1`(уже с `id`) я генерирую теги `<а>` которых указываю
       ссылки на заголовок(`h1`) и заполняю ими таблицу слева(`Table of Contents`).

Код: [исходный код](https://codepen.io/wizzy228/pen/yZqXQy)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // ADD IDs
    var topics = jQuery('.content h1');

    topics.each(function(n) {
        $(this).attr("id", "anchor_" + n);
    });
    var anchors = jQuery('.content h1');


    //CREATE TABLE BLOCK

    jQuery('#table_contents').append(`
        <div class="table_inner">
            <p>Table of Contents <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></p>
            <div class="topics__anchors">
                <ul>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    `);

    anchors.each(function(n) {

        //console.log(jQuery(this).attr('id'));

         jQuery('.topics__anchors ul').append(`
             <li><a href="${"#"+jQuery(this).attr('id')  }">${(n+1)+". " + jQuery(this).text()}</a></li>
         `);



    });
    var anchorsBlock=jQuery('.topics__anchors');



    jQuery('.table_inner p').click(function () {
        if (!anchorsBlock.hasClass('active')){
            anchorsBlock.addClass('active');
            anchorsBlock.show();
        }else {
            anchorsBlock.removeClass('active');
            anchorsBlock.hide();
        }
    });



    //ANIMATE SCROLL
    var anchorsLinks=jQuery('.topics__anchors a');

    anchorsLinks.click(function (e) {

        anchorsLinks.removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        console.log('You clicked a-tag   ' + e.target);

        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        jQuery('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 300);

    });


});
```

И если кликать на ссылки в таблице то нас перемещает к соответствующему заголовке.

Проблема в том, что код работает хорошо на `Windows` и `Linux`,
но если тестить на `MacOS` то ссылки не кликабельны(повсюду используется Chrome Browser).
Потестить можно тут -> [Пример кода](http://montana-studio.zzz.com.ua/)
В чем может быть проблема?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тема закрыта.

Нужно ссылкам прописать `display:inline-block;` 
Тогда на Маках все ок)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте Z-index ваших элементов в CSS если его нет то установите. И попробуйте снова сбросив кеш.

Еще можете попробовать сделать так

```
$('.topics__anchors a').on('click', function(){


        $(this).removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        console.log('You clicked a-tag   ' + e.target);

        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        jQuery('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 300);


});
```

А лучше вот таким образом

```
$('#table_contents').on('.topics__anchors a', 'click', function(e){


        $(this).removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        console.log('You clicked a-tag   ' + e.target);

        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        jQuery('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 300);


});
```

Comment: не помогло( Спасибо

Comment: Дополните код вашего поста CSS и HTML.

Comment: Дополнил на codepen

Comment: Спасибо. Но оба варианта не работают на MacOS